# Integration database on micro-services

Tags: database-design, microservices

I need some wisdom on this. Currently I'm learning about micro-services architecture, and so I decided to make a simple project in a micro-services architecture. The project I'm building is just a simple Inventory management application, where the functionality is, well just to add Item and information about it. So at the current state, I have a:

- Authentication server
- Item management server

The Authentication server has responsibilities to handle registering a `User`, changing its password, and exchanging http basic auth to jwt token to be used in Item management server. Item management server is a basic CRUD server for `Item`.

The way I do this, I create a single database, both server connecting to this database and I have another repo that runs migration on the database that satisfies both servers. Currently I'm using PostgreSQL. Let's say this is the schema:

```
MyAppDb:
  - UserTable
    - id ;; UUID
    - username 
    - password
  - ItemTable
    - id
    - owner ;; foreign key to UserTable id
    - name
```

[This](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/IntegrationDatabase.html) article states that using a single database for many apps is bad, because your server is actually tightly coupled to the others through the database. If I'm going to apply this, then I have to change how I work with the database:

```
MyUserDb:
  - UserTable
    - id ;; UUID
    - username 
    - password

MyItemDb:
  - ItemTable
    - id 
    - owner ;; not sure what the type of this, should this be a plain UUID?
    - name
```

So the question is:

1. What would be the suitable data type for `owner` in `ItemTable` that previously points to user id?
2. Since I'm no longer using shared databases, for example, if I need to query an `Item` and I also want to display its `owner`, does that mean I have to do an HTTP call (assuming I'm using REST) to the Authentication server (assuming the Authentication server is capable of doing this)?

Comment: Why would the type of the field need to change?

Comment: In any case, a gateway/backend for frontend might help you.  See [here](https://developer.ibm.com/patterns/create-backend-for-frontend-application-architecture/) and [here](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hi, thank you for responding. Because based on the article given at my post and also [this](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html) one, having a single database across the entire micro-services is considered an anti-pattern and I don't have any experience to deny that claim. So based on that, if I want to use single database per service, how do I describe that `owner` in `ItemTable` points to `id` in `UserTable`? I am under the impression that I can't use foreign key cross databases (PostgreSQL).

Comment: Each Microservice should indeed be responsible for it's own data. If a request comes in at microservice A, microservice A should not query microservice B. If B depends on data from A, whenever data in A is changed it should generate an event which B can react to to duplicate the data.

Comment: @RikD So with that reasoning, with the above example, I should create a duplicate user table? Not a complete one of course, just a partial one ,maybe only contains `id` and `username`.

Comment: The issue is *scalability.*  What that means is that you don't want services competing with each other for the same data.  One way to solve that is by *caching the data.*

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I don't think you should solve a problem that you don't have yet.  If your application requires data from a common source, then your application requires data from a common source.  Put a microservice in front of that data, and let the other microservices access it.  Or, y'know, use a common database and cache the values.  The only way you're going to know for sure is to try it and see what works in your situation.

Comment: In my opinion, micro services trades complexity for separation. So your solution will be more complex compared to a monolith. The advantage would be that microservices are independent, so can use different tech, deployed independently, developer needs only needs to be an expert on a single service, etc. Most of these advantages are only relevant for larger systems. And you typically need to be very familiar with the domain to know where to draw the borders between the services. There are some fun horror stories out there about micro services done incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

A general idea to cut your issues down with the aim of Microservices paradigm would be a strategic pattern of DDD which called context mapping. In the context mapping you define the type of the relations between your bounded context and you shape your domain models which may seem are duplicated in names, though these are different in usage.

For the example that you mentioned, it seems that you have two bounded context, means *Item* and *User*. In the *Item* bounded context (i.e. ItemService) you can specify a reference to your *User* entity via a username or an id. Here the *User* entity of the *Item* context (you can also call it *Customer* entity) can makes a different sense from the *User* context. For instance, you don't need the password of the user in *Item* context. So, you can accomplish an eventual contingency inside the *Item* context which is updated by *User* context's events (e.g. a username changed or new user created).

In this scenario, you have your relational databases throughout your application. If you need more data of the *User* in the *Item* context, you can simply use a restful api to query the needed data.

The source of truth of the *User* entity is the *User* context (i.e. UserService). So the *Item* context is a gainer not an actor of it. At this point, you have independent services which can own their databases and infrastructures.